# Distinguish .nb that has been saved from new .nb

Tags: function-construction, notebooks, built-in-symbols, system

There may be many ways to distinguish `.nb` that has been saved from new .nb

I found that in `NotebookInformation[]` may be useful.

It seems for `.nb` that has been saved, `NotebookInformation[]` start with

`"FileName"`

[image]

Whereas for new `.nb`, there is no `"FileName"` part.

[image]

From the experts' point of view, this may be inaccurate sometimes, or didn't considered rare, special cases. (Hyperlink or Cloud related, etc...)

If there is a better way than this(or equally good), please introduce it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Quiet@NotebookFileName[]
```

returns name of current notebook in the case it was saved

or

`$Failed` in the case it was never saved.